# Briefly run / Restart sublime text from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I don't want to run an external program (subl - sublime text) *at* a certain point of time, I want to run it **for** a certain amount of time. I basically need to boot up the program for 10 seconds then kill it - multiple times - because of its install and update process.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this in my script

```
/usr/bin/subl
SPID="$(ps -A | grep sublime_text | awk '{print $1}')"
sleep 5
kill "$SPID"
unset "$SPID"
```

Comment: You're better off with capturing the returned PID instead of searching on it in case you have multiple instances running: Run it: `/usr/bin/subl` and then capture the id: `SPID=$!`

Comment: @yk11 sublime text seems to launch the editor on a separate process to the process that spawns using `/usr/bin/subl`, otherwise I would have just used @chepner's answer

Answer (score 2):

Use `timeout`:

```
timeout 5s <program>
```

You can also specify the signal which need to be passed to terminating the process.

```
timeout -s9 5s <program>
```

(OR)

```
timeout --signal=KILL 5s <program>
```

**Test:**

```
$ time timeout 5s sleep 40

real    0m5.002s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.001s
```

Comment: Updated answer. It is because of `timeout` sending `SIGTERM` signal and that may be handled by `subl`.

Comment: `timeout -s9 5s subl`, `timeout -s9 5s /usr/bin/subl` and `timeout --signal=KILL 5s subl`

Comment: Command seems to be ok. Try this: `timeout -s9 5s sleep 40`. Is is it working ??

Comment: Yes and `timeout 5s nautilus` works. Maybe its a subl specific thing

Answer (score 2):

You may have a `timeout` command on your system, which uses a standard alarm signal to terminate a process. I've never quite understood why no shell provides access to this feature as a builtin. If you don't have `timeout` on your system, you can simulate it with

```
my_program & pid=$!
sleep 10
kill "$pid"
```